# Quando o timer termina

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorjs

Bom dia, estou com uma duvida na qual ja estou trabalhando a algum tempo. Eu tenho 1 timer com contagem decrescente, quando o timer chegar a 0, queria que uns botões invisíveis ficassem visíveis.
Estou utilizando o Meteor JS com o seguinte package: https://atmospherejs.com/flyandi/reactive-countdown

```
E tenho o seguinte código:


  var countdown1 = new ReactiveCountdown(10, {
    interval: 500,
        complete: function() {
            var button1= document.getElementById("startMission1")
            button1.style.display='none'},
        });

Template.tabernaMission.events({
'click #startMission1': function(event) {
        countdown1.start(function() {
    });
})

Template.tabernaMission.helpers({
 getCountdown1: function() {
        return countdown1.get();
    },
})
```

Comment: Qual seria o problema? O que não estaria funcionando?

Comment: o problema e que quando o timer chega a 0 quero que os butões se tornem visiveis, e nao estou a conseguir

Comment: pois esse e o meu problema nao esta entrando na função, sim os botao es com display none

Comment: Se tiver como disponibilizar o código mínimo para que eu conseguisse reproduzir aqui. Tentei pela página do plugin mas não consegui implementar.

Comment: editei, disponível tudo o código que tenho

Comment: estou a utilizar meteor, blaze.js e um package

Comment: Já olhou no console se aparece algum erro?

Comment: sim, e nao da nenhum erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui utilizando o SetTimeout

```
setTimeout(() => {
        var disableButton1 = document.getElementById("startMission1")
        var disableButton2 = document.getElementById("startMission2")
        var disableButton3 = document.getElementById("startMission3")

        disableButton1.style.display='block'
        disableButton2.style.display='block'
        disableButton3.style.display='block'
 }, 50000)
```